# Do I still need to wrap Published Property wrapper object update with DispatchQueue.main.async

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm having my code as below

```
class WebSocketManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var messages: [String] = []

    private let socket: URLSessionWebSocketTask =
        URLSession(configuration: .default).webSocketTask(with: URL(string: "ws://localhost:8082")!)

    func receiveMessage() {
        socket.receive { result in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error Detected: \(error)")
            case .success(let message):
                switch message {
                case .string(let text):
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.messages.append(text)
                    }
                default:
                    print("Received data different format data")
                }
                self.receiveMessage()
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm wondering if I should still wrap the `self.messages.append(text)` with `DispatchQueue.main.async`

```
                case .string(let text):
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.messages.append(text)
                    }
```

or I don't need to wrap it

```
                case .string(let text):
                    self.messages.append(text)
```

since it is processed internally by SwiftUI

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not *processed internally by SwiftUI*, and if the code is as provided then *yes* you should redirect changes in main queue explicitly.

However, if you wrap your observable object as `MainActor` (available since iOS 15 !!), as shown below, then you don't need such redirection and can make direct assignment - main actor wrapper will do else.

```
@MainActor                                // << here !!
class WebSocketManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var messages: [String] = []
...
```